# UDF python in Hive with File Json

Tags: hadoop, hive, user-defined-functions, hiveql, ambari

I have two problem with Hive view in Ambari.

**1. Problem 1:I have script :**

```
<br>DELETE FILE /user/admin/hive/scripts/MKT_UDF/fb_audit_ads_creatives.py;
<br>ADD FILE /user/admin/hive/scripts/MKT_UDF/fb_audit_ads_creatives.py;
<br>SELECT TRANSFORM (line) USING 'python fb_audit_ads_creatives.py' as (ad_id) FROM stg_fb_audit_ads_creatives_json where date_time='2018-05-05';
```

**I run it many times, It's run smoothly. But on some times, I get error:**

You can see it: Here's [Log error](https://justpaste.it/4s05a)

I think it's due config (Hive, Ambari, ...time out...v.v.)

**Problem 2: I have file json:**

```
{
  "body": "https://www.facebook.com/groupkiemhieptinhduyen #truongsinhquyet #sapramat #tsq #game3d",
  "thumbnail_url": "https://external.xx.fbcdn.net/safe_image.php?d=AQDU01asRxdnCObW&w=64&h=64&url=https%3A%2F%2Fscontent.xx.fbcdn.net%2Fv%2Ft15.0-10%",
  "campaign_id": "23842841688740666"
}
```

**I use script HQL above  and UDF Python:**

```
for line in sys.stdin:
data = json.loads(line)
print (data)
print(data['thumbnail_url']
```

**I run it's okay.**

**But with UDF Python:**

```
for line in sys.stdin:
data = json.loads(line)
print (data)
print(data['body']
```

**I get error:** [Log error](https://justpaste.it/5zpdg)

**Can you help me?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of working with python, I recommend to try this UDTF that allows working on [json columns within hive](https://github.com/CyberAgent/hive-jq-udtf) It is then possible to manipulate large json and fetch needed data in a distributed and optimized way.